# Challenge while optimizing algo by SIMD NEON

Tags: simd, neon, cortex-a8

I am trying to optimize my algorithm in neon SIMD .

Scalar code :

```
for (int y = 1; y < (height - 1); y++) {
    int height_offs = y * width;
    for (int x = 1; x < (width - 1); x++) {
        dst[height_offs + x] = (
                src[(height_offs - width) + (x + 1)] -
                src[(height_offs - width) + (x - 1)] +
                 // current row
                src[(height_offs)         + (x + 1)] -
                src[(height_offs)         + (x - 1)] +
                 // next row
                src[(height_offs + width) + (x + 1)] -
                src[(height_offs + width) + (x - 1)]
            );
    }
}
```

But I found that width and height parameter are not constant. These values are varying by outside iteration. For example width =7 /8 /9 /10 /11 /12 /13 (/ means or). So I thought to take reminder like width%4 and will calculate the `dst[height_offs + x]` for the remaining reminder values. For example if width is 7 means width loop run from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 .So I can process vector as 0,1,2,3 and remaining 4,5,6 with 7 as copy of 6. But for each reminder value that is 3,2,1 I have to write a separate implementation which will affect the performance and I will loose the befits of SIMD. I want to ask following questions.

- Is there any generic implementation I can do to avoid  rewriting the logic for each reminder value (for 3,2 and 1)`
- Is it a good idea to use SIMD here

**Note:** I am optimizing Lucas Kanade Algo where I have to do derivative calculation on each pyramid level.Because of this the height and width of the image got changed .So I can not avoid changing values for width and height .

Vector Code: (not working properly.Need to do some changes inside)

```
uint32x4_t src_vector32x4__prev0,src_vector32x4__prev1,src_vector32x4__prev2;
uint32x4_t  src_vector32x4__curr0,src_vector32x4__curr1,src_vector32x4__curr2;
uint32x4_t  src_vector32x4__next0,src_vector32x4__next1,src_vector32x4__next2;
uint32x4_t s1,s2,s3,add_32x4u;
int32x4_t dst_vector32x4;
uint32_t Idx ;

/* Load destination data into the destination vector register. */
dst_vector32x4 = vld1q_s32(dst);
for (int32_t y = 1; y < (src_height - 1); ++y) {

    int32_t height_offs = y * src_width;
    for (int32_t x = 1; x < (src_width - 1); x+=4) {
        Idx = height_offs + x ;
        src_vector32x4__prev0 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs - src_width) + (x - 1)]); // 00 01 02 03
        src_vector32x4__prev2 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs - src_width) + (x + 1)]); // 02 03 04 05

        src_vector32x4__curr0 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs)             + (x - 1)]); // 10 11 12 13
        src_vector32x4__curr2 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs)             + (x + 1)]); // 12 13 14 15

        src_vector32x4__next0 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs + src_width) + (x - 1)]); // 20 21 22 23
        src_vector32x4__next2 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs + src_width) + (x + 1)]); // 22 23 24 25

        //src_vector32x4__prev1 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs - src_width) + (x)]);   // 01 02 03 04
        //src_vector32x4__curr1 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs)             + (x)]);   // 11 12 13 14
        //src_vector32x4__next1 = vld1q_u32(&src[(height_offs + src_width) + (x)]);   // 21 22 23 24

        s1 = vsubq_u32(src_vector32x4__prev2,src_vector32x4__prev0);
        s2 = vsubq_u32(src_vector32x4__curr2,src_vector32x4__curr0);
        s3 = vsubq_u32(src_vector32x4__next2,src_vector32x4__next0);

        add_32x4u = vaddq_u32(s1,vaddq_u32(s2,s3));
        dst_vector32x4 = vreinterpretq_s32_u32(add_32x4u);
        /*Store a destination vector into destination buffer*/
        vst1q_s32(&dst[Idx],dst_vector32x4);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a flat 3x3 filter, so it's separable into a 1x3 and a 3x1 pass. Do you also want to do that? As for the "leftovers", can you pad it with zeroes?

Comment: for leftover it may be 3 rows padding or 2 rows padding or 1 rows padding .It will decide at run time .AS height and width is updating on every loop and got changed from 7,8,9,10...that is reminder 3,2,1.SO I have to put if condition to check the reminder and pad the leftover by that many times if condition is loop will  affect the performance

Comment: I have updated My code with vecorization .But this is not correct implementation as I did not take care of the leftcover